# Oracle performance tuning for stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A scenario encountered recently where I have lots of select statements as:

```
and  (UPPER(Table1.col1) LIKE UPPER(v_param1)||'%' or v_param1 is NULL)
and  (UPPER(Table2.col2) LIKE UPPER(v_param2)||'%' or v_param2 is NULL)
```

`v_param1` & `v_param2` are inputs to the stored procedure, I need to optimize the query. Is there any way to check if the `v_param1,v_param1` are NULL then no need to check for the first condition before Or.

Comment: One thing you can do is create a function based index on upper of column 1 and column 2

Comment: Thanks for the response, That won't suit my requirement as there are many selection with and clause and creating index on those will slow down performance for other services doing insert or update to those tables.

Comment: Can't you store Table1.col1 & Table1.col2 in uppercase. That would avoid overload of converting them to uppercase during querying.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that or and change the condition like below

and upper(Table1.col1) like upper(v_param1)||'%'
and upper(Table2.col2) like upper(v_param2)||'%'

Note: if param value is null then it will execute the condition like "upper(col1) like '%'"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do is to switch the order in which the conditions are evaluated:

```
and  (v_param1 is NULL or UPPER(Table1.col1) LIKE UPPER(v_param1)||'%'  )
and  (v_param2 is NULL or UPPER(Table2.col2) LIKE UPPER(v_param2)||'%'  )
```

Oracle does not guarantee to short-circuit the OR evaluation, but leading with the NULL test gives it a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use stored procedure then you can construct your query dynamically in pl/sql, bind variables and execute query using dbms_sql.

```
...
  sSQL varchar2(32767) := 'select col1, col2 from Table1';
  iCurrId            number := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  iCurRes            number;
begin
  -- constant conditions
  sSQL := sSQL||' where col3 = :column3_value';

  -- add condition for v_param1 if it is not null  
  if v_param1 is not null then
    sSQL := sSQL||' and UPPER(Table1.col1) LIKE :v_param1_search_value';
  end if;

  -- add condition for v_param2 if it is not null  
  if v_param2 is not null then
    sSQL := sSQL||' and UPPER(Table1.col2) LIKE :v_param2_search_value';
  end if;

  -- parse cursor
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(
    C             => iCurrId,
    STATEMENT     => sSQL,
    LANGUAGE_FLAG => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE
  );

  -- bind variables
  DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE( C => iCurrId, NAME => 'column3_value', VALUE => 'abcd');

  if v_param1 is not null then
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE( C => iCurrId, NAME => 'v_param1_search_value', VALUE => UPPER(v_param1)||'%');
  end if;

  if v_param2 is not null then
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE( C => iCurrId, NAME => 'v_param2_search_value', VALUE => UPPER(v_param2)||'%');
  end if;

  -- execute query
  iCurRes := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(iCurrId);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
AND (
  CASE
    WHEN v_param2 IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE UPPER(Table2.col2)
  END LIKE UPPER(v_param2)
  ||'%'
OR v_param2      IS NULL)
```